# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null, moving script to body doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I've googled this error up but I still cannot solve it. I add things to the DB, and when I set value to "1" and click "get data" I receive "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" error.

I've moved my `<script>` to `<body>` but the error is still there. It also doesn't show any data. Any suggestions on how to solve:
* Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null error
* show data required?

I can't use jQuery just pure JS.

Code:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"><br/>
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"><br/>
    <button id="addButton">Add Data</button>
    <input type="text" id="key" placeholder="Key"></br>
    <button id="getPersonButton">getPersonButton</button>

<script>

    var db;

    function indexedDBOk() {
        return "indexedDB" in window;
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

        //No support? Go in the corner and pout.
        if(!indexedDBOk) return;

        var openRequest = indexedDB.open("idarticle_people2",1);

        openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
            var thisDB = e.target.result;

            if(!thisDB.objectStoreNames.contains("people")) {
                thisDB.createObjectStore("people", {autoIncrement:true});
            }
        }

        openRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
            console.log("running onsuccess");

            db = e.target.result;

            //Listen for add clicks
            document.querySelector("#addButton").addEventListener("click", addPerson, false);
            document.querySelector("#getPersonButton").addEventListener("click", getPerson, false);
        }

        openRequest.onerror = function(e) {
            //Do something for the error
        }


    },false);




    function addPerson(e) {
        var name = document.querySelector("#name").value;
        var email = document.querySelector("#email").value;

        console.log("About to add "+name+"/"+email);

        //Get a transaction
        //default for OS list is all, default for type is read
        var transaction = db.transaction(["people"],"readwrite");
        //Ask for the objectStore
        var store = transaction.objectStore("people");

        //Define a person
        var person = {
            name:name,
            email:email,
            created:new Date()
        }

        //Perform the add
        var request = store.add(person);

        request.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log("Error",e.target.error.name);
            //some type of error handler
        }

        request.onsuccess = function(e) {
            console.log("Woot! Did it");
        }
    }

    function getPerson(e) {
        var key = document.querySelector("#key").value;
        if(key === "" || isNaN(key)) return;

        var transaction = db.transaction(["people"],"readonly");
        var store = transaction.objectStore("people");

        var request = store.get(Number(key));

        request.onsuccess = function(e) {
            var result = e.target.result;
            console.dir(result);
            if(result) {
                var s = "&lt;h2>Key "+key+"&lt;/h2>&lt;p>";
                for(var field in result) {
                    s+= field+"="+result[field]+"&lt;br/>";
                }
                document.querySelector("#status").innerHTML = s;
            } else {
                document.querySelector("#status").innerHTML = "&lt;h2>No match&lt;/h2>";
            }
        }
    }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your id="status" HTML element ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the content of the element with id `status`, you need to add an element with this id to the document first:

```
<body>
  <div id='status'></div>
```

After that, you will be able to access it via `querySelector`:

```
document.querySelector("#status")
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the `innerHTML` of the element having the `id` of `status`. Since there is no such element, the result of

```
document.querySelector("#status")
```

is `null`, therefore if you try to use

```
document.querySelector("#status").innerHTML
```

, then you will get the error mentioned in the question. You can solve the problem by making sure that you have an html having `id="status"` when the code tries to use its `innerHTML`. Also, you can do something like this:

```
var context = document.querySelector("#status");
if (!!context) {
    //do something with context.innerHTML
}
```